# Rails gem for a calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, rubygems

i need to implement a calendar on this app im building. The client mentioned google calendar so im looking for the closest possible. Any recommendations?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: ?? recommendations on gems or any kind @jcm?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4):

You can find some in railscast by ryan bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars .

There is also a revised version for this http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised . You can also integrate google calendar to your app using google calendar api http://blog.baugues.com/google-calendar-api-oauth2-and-ruby-on-rails .

Calendar in rails https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails and for it's other jquery function http://fullcalendar.io/

Hope this help you!

Comment: I can recommend the full_calendar because there is an option where you are able to fetch google calendar events see [the docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/)